# Random ADC value in PIC

Tags: pic, adc, mplabx

I am reading ADC values on my dsPIC33EP512MU810 when I slide my linearized slide POT. But,what I get is random values, I can read some ADC values but it is not getting updated in each position in the slider. Also,I can't understand why all the buffers are getting updated with different adc values.

Also,the buffers are getting updated randomly for e.g ADC1BUF1 gets updated in the 1st run, then later ADC1BUFA gets updated in the next position in 2nd run and so on. I am using a break point on the line 'reading ADC Value' and debugging it to see the ADC value. Below is my code and also I have attached the output images.

```
void initAdc(void);
void Delay_us(unsigned int);
int  i, j;
int ADCValue;

int main(void)
{ 

PLLFBD = 58;/* M = 60*/
CLKDIVbits.PLLPOST = 0;/* N1 = 2*/
CLKDIVbits.PLLPRE = 0;/* N2 = 2*/
OSCTUN = 0;
/* Initiate Clock Switch to Primary Oscillator with PLL (NOSC = 0x3) */
__builtin_write_OSCCONH(0x03);
__builtin_write_OSCCONL(0x01);
while (OSCCONbits.COSC!=0x3);//wait for clockl switch to occur
while (_LOCK==0);//wait for PLL lock at 60MIPS
initAdc();
while(1)
   {
     AD1CON1bits.SAMP = 1;
     Delay_us(10);// Sample for 100 us
    // AD1CHS0bits.CH0SA = ch;  //select analog input channel
     AD1CON1bits.SAMP = 0;   //start the conversion
     while(!AD1CON1bits.DONE);// Wait for the conversion to complete
     //AD1CON1bits.DONE = 0;// Clear conversion done status bit
     ADCValue=ADC1BUF0;// Read the ADC conversion result*/
     Nop();
   } 
}

void initAdc(void)
{

/* Set port configuration */ 
ANSELA = ANSELB = ANSELC = ANSELD = ANSELE = ANSELG = 0x0000;
TRISBbits.TRISB12 = 1; //RB12 as input
ANSELBbits.ANSB12 = 1;// Ensure A7/RB12 is analog
//ANSELEbits.ANSE6 = 1;//AN30/RE6 is analog
/* Initialize and enable ADC module */
AD1CON1 = 0x0004;//bit 10 and bit 2 set to 1
AD1CON2 = 0x0000;
AD1CON3 = 0x000F;
AD1CON4 = 0x0000;
AD1CHS0 = 0x0005;
AD1CHS123 = 0x0000;
AD1CSSH = 0x0000;
AD1CSSL = 0x0000;
AD1CON1bits.ADON = 1;
Delay_us(20);
}
void Delay_us(unsigned int delay)
{
    for (i = 0; i < delay; i++)
    {__asm__ volatile ("repeat #39");
    __asm__ volatile ("nop");
    }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: It might help to punctuate and format your question.

Comment: Have you tried putting a known good voltage on the ADC input? This would help to confirm your setup/code. Also, have you looked at the output of the slide pot on a scope? It could be noisy, and you are seeing that.